# How do I know which OSBundleLibrary to include when using XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel

It seems that I am doing something wrong or the linker is not very good in xcode (I imagine is the first situation :) ) but I found that I need to manually add the OSBundleLibrary references on the plist.

The problem is that sometimes I don't know which bundles should I include, for example, I am building a kernel extension and I am using VFS, it compiles but when I try to load it into the kernel it complains that it can not resolve all the VFS functions.

I usually include "com.apple.kernel.bsd" but when I check samples of VFS I can see "com.apple.kpi.bsd", a bit confusing.

Can anyone share some light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, there is a reference link with all the extensions:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptDependencies/kext_dependencies.html